# mysql select row between 2 time

Tags: mysql, time

i have a table with time slots, one column with start time, one colun with end time, 12 slots time per day, example :

| start | end | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 230 | 10 |
| 231 | 400 | 11 |
| 401 | 500 | 12 |
| 2216 | 100 | 9 |

integer in column 'start' and column 'end' are time in 24h format. ex : 2216 = 22:16

In this example, is it possible to select value where time is 00:02 (so value 9, 00:02 is between 22:16 and 01:00) ?

i try :

`SELECT value FROM table WHERE '2' BETWEEN 'start' AND 'end'`

without success when the time slot sought overlaps...
Column must be in time format instead of integer for this query ?

Thanks !

Comment: What's the logic for saying 100 is after 2216 - is it simply that start is > end?

Comment: you are right, it helped me, i'll answer with the right solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE start < 2 AND end > 2
```

Comment: humm this query return no result, no values in start column are < 2 in the example. Query must return value 9, time 00:02 is between 22:16 and 01:00

Answer (score 0):

The good query is :

`SELECT value FROM table WHERE ((start > end AND '2' <= end) OR ('2' >= start AND '2'<= end));`

Thanks @P.Salmon